# hyphen - showing � this symbol in html view

Tags: html, database, encoding

I am getting � this symbol in HTML code but in a database it storing properly with the hyphen(-).
Here I am expecting "`Hong Kong - Macau 04 nights / 05 days`" and now html displaying with "`Hong Kong � Macau 04 nights / 05 days`"

Comment: please edit with your code...

Comment: sounds like a unicode character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this to your index.html head?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

> A character in UTF8 can be from 1 to 4 bytes long. UTF-8 can represent any character in the Unicode standard. UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. UTF-8 is the preferred encoding for e-mail and web pages

[from w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp)

Comment: I have added `<html lang="en">
<head >

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding problem, you need to find out what encoding your HTML files is in, it must be what you editor produces.
add meta tag like this and replace the UTF-8 to whatever your editor produces

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```